# Android, cómo poner avatar por defecto en un ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

Una duda que no veo cómo resolver:

Tengo un listView de usuarios que me muestra dos campos por usuario. El primero muestra la imagen de su avatar y el otro, el nombre del usuario. Estos datos están almacenados en un servidor remoto. La imagen del avatar coincide con su id de usuario, así el usuario 1 tiene asignada la imagen "http://www.URLDELSITIO/1.jpg"; el usuario 2, la imagen "http://www.URLDELSITIO/2.jpg"... y así miles.

El problema es que algunos usuarios no tienen definida una imagen de avatar y, por lo tanto, aunque yo componga la url para obtener su imagen, ésta me sale en blanco.

A mi me gustaría poner una imagen por defecto para aquellos usuario que no tengan un avatar definido, pero la verdad es que no veo cómo hacerlo.

Así lo tengo hecho con Picasso.

```
    ImageView avatarView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAvatarMensa);


        Picasso.with(context)
                .load("https://URLDELSITIO/"+codigo_usuario.get(position) +".jpg")
                .into(avatarView);


TextView textView1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);
textView1.setText(nombre_usuario);
```

Esto funciona bien, pero aquellas URLS de usuarios que no tienen una imagen subida (y por lo tanto no existe el fichero de imagen) no me muestra nada. Sale en blanco.

Lo he intentado con el layout xml, de esta manera:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAvatarMensa"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar_defecto"
        />
```

Es decir, definiendo una imagen en el archivo XML, pero tampoco me funciona.

¿Algún consejo? Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para desplegar una imagen por defecto antes de que la imagen sea cargada puedes usar el método `.placeholder()`.

Ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
  Picasso.get()
                .load("https://URLDELSITIO/"+codigo_usuario.get(position) +".jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_defecto) //imagen por defecto.
                .into(avatarView);
```

Pero tu tienes otro caso:

> pero aquellas URLS de usuarios que no tienen una imagen subida (y
>   por lo tanto no existe el fichero de imagen) no me muestra nada. Sale
>   en blanco.

**En este caso puedes usar el método `.error()` en el caso de no encontrar el recurso y de esta forma asignar la imagen predeterminad**a:

```
  Picasso.get()
                .load("https://URLDELSITIO/"+codigo_usuario.get(position) +".jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_defecto) //imagen por defecto.
                .error(R.drawable.avatar_defecto) //Imagen al suceder un error en la descarga.
                .into(avatarView);
```

---

Puedes revisar información sobre estos métodos en la [documentación de Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: Genial! Al final resulta que era más sencillo de lo que yo pensaba (que pensaba que era imposible). Desde luego con cada respuesta suya mi nivel de novato queda cada vez más lejos, porque aprendo muchísimo de usted. Muchas gracias!!!